# Do file permissions of a static website matter?

Tags: file-permissions, web-hosting

My static website is hosted on a Linux server. Does it really matter what my file permissions are (755 vs. 777, for example)? I mean, how could someone possibly alter my content without having my username and password?

In particular, I am not even able to see the contents of the `/home` directory of the server...

So why is it said that setting to 777 is not advisable?

Comment: Because it's foolish to give unnecessary access to a folder without a specific reason to do so? This is like asking *Why is it not advisable to leave my keys in the ignition when I park at night? Chances that anyone will look are slim; my street doesn't get pedestrian traffic at night very often.* *very often* is irrelevant; it just takes once, and you don't have a car any longer. Why be irresponsible and give rights that you don't need to give?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what is the platform, setting file permissions should never be considered an innocuous decision to make, even for a website's static content.

File permissions imply we're talking about files (that your webserver may or may not serve as static content).

If we're talking about files (that your webserver may or may not serve as static content), we're talking about handlers for the content types "attached" (i.e., configured) to those files.

If we're talking about handlers, we're talking about executable code.

If we're talking about executable code, there may be still-unknown implementation flaws *in the handlers* (even if nowhere else) that would suffice and allow exploits over themselves, or the webserver, or the file system's content they access.

Some of these exploits could very well be capable to overwrite or execute files that *you once believed* would be "out of reach" of your server's handlers (but in fact, are not, for what the compromised handler is executing by then) and that you left with read/write/execute flags set...

Hence, why file permissions, in absence of a formal proof that 100% of the software is bug-free (which, *to say the least*, isn't exactly easy to get).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run only html files at all then there is no issue but If you want to execute any php file then your directory permissions should be 777 and php files permissions should be 755 otherwise you will be run into 500 internal error